# Checkbox change event bubbles up to parent li element while using e.stopPropagation()

Tags: javascript, html

I've added a change event listener `input[type='checkbox']` element, but even though I've included the `e.stopPropagation()` in my JS code, the event seems to bubble up to the click listener on the `<li>` element.

My HTML structure:

```
<li> 
  <label class="checkboxContainer">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>
Lorem ipsum
</li>
```

It's important to note that that checkbox element doesn't take up any space. Rather, the label element is customized to create a custom checkbox. Adding the eventListener to the label has the same effect.

My JS code:

1. eventListener on checkbox change event

```
const checkbox = document.querySelector(".checkboxContainer input");
checkbox.addEventListener("change", e => {
      e.stopPropagation();
      //rest of code goes here
}):
```

2. eventListener on li click event

```
const li = document.querySelector('li');
li.addEventListener("click", e => {
     //code goes here
});
```

See image below to get a sense of what I want to achieve
[image: todo]
When I click on the blue area, the todo should fade out (the checkbox event). When I click on the text of the li, the edit screen should toggle. (the li click event)
Now when I click the blue area the li event get's triggered to. So the todo fades out and the edit screen shows up.

I would be very grateful for any suggestion how I can solve this problem!

Comment: Why are you attaching events to both parent & child ?

Comment: This code is in the context of a todo item. The change event triggers the li to fade out. (aka completed) The click event triggers an edit popup to change the todo text content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** if you trigger the click event only on the text (which is all you need according to your example) it works:

```js
const checkbox = document.querySelector(".checkboxContainer input");
const span = document.querySelector('.edit');

checkbox.addEventListener("change", e => {
   console.log("only blue fade out")
});

span.addEventListener("click", e => {
  console.log("change text")
});
```

```html
<li> 
  <label class="checkboxContainer">
 <input type="checkbox">
 <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>
  <span class="edit">Lorem ipsum</span>
</li>
```

The problem your are facing is that you are clicking the event on li first.

As soon as you change the checkbox you are first clicking the li as this is the parent element.

```
const checkbox = document.querySelector(".checkboxContainer input");

checkbox.addEventListener("change", e => {
    e.stopPropagation();
        console.log("checkbox")
});

const li = document.querySelector('li');
li.addEventListener("click", e => {
    console.log("li")
});

// Onchange Checkbox CONSOLE: 
li
checkbox

// Onclick li CONSOLE: 
li
```

Comment: You're right, but how could I alter my code such that the checkbox is still inside the li element?

Comment: I edited my answer and I hope this works for you. If yes it would be great if you can vote for my answer. Good luck with your work.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because the event that you are stopping from propagation is not the same event that's being captured in the `li` event handler. There are two events here, changed and clicked. Just add click as well as change to your checkbox event listener and it should make it work:

```js
const checkbox = document.querySelector(".checkboxContainer input");
checkbox.addEventListener("click", e => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    //rest of code goes here
}):
```

Although it would be problematic cause you're hiding your checkbox, so maybe set it up on your label.